# Rails query date filter adapting to different cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date

Firts, I filter some reservations based on their status. Then I need to filter them by date. BUT, the kind of filter that I have to do sometimes changes. This are all the different cases:

1. Need to filter reservations that have their `start_date` or `end_date` between a range a dates.
2. Need to filter reservations that have ONLY their `start_date` between a range of dates.
3. Need to filter reservations that have ONLY their `end_date` between a range of dates.

I need to do something like:

```
Reservation.filter(reservations, params[:filter])
  .where('start_date between...
```

Which must work for each of the cases I specified. I want to avoid having and actual `if else` clause with many options and just use one single query.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I where you I will break it down in smaller pieces. I know you want to avoid multiple queries and `if else` but I think you should start there and optimize later. That would give you a good baseline to know if the optimize solution returns the same results.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that, and then I found out I only needed one if else. Thanks again.

Comment: Federico, if you can please add an answer so others can learn from your experience.

Comment: Sory for the delay, i managed to do it differently so I don't know if it counts as a solution to the problem. Should I still answer with what I did?